# Selenium always gives org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The text "Congratulations!" apprears on the site only when the transaction is successful.

I am trying to capture the text of this element using JavascriptExecutor as the type is set to hidden but selenium always displays:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='form-header']//div[contains(text(),'Congratulations')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

Code 1 (Not Working)

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@class='form-header']//div[contains(text(),'Congratulations')]));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String text = (String)js.executeScript("return arguments[0].value",ele);
System.out.println(text);
```

Code 2 (Not Working)

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@class='form-header']//div[contains(text(),'Congratulations')]));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    String text = (String)js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML",ele);
System.out.println(text);
```

The HTML code for this part is as follows:

```
<input id="hdnWindowLocationHost" name="hdnWindowLocationHost" type="hidden" value="/" data-value="themes/custom">
<div id="sgw" class="sgw SGW-header">
             
        </div>
<div class="page">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="form">
                <div class="form-header">
                    <div class="headline">Congratulations!</div>
                    Your password has been reset. Please log in below with your Username and password.
                </div>
```

Comment: Does the transaction currently work? Or is there an iframe on the page?

Comment: I would try with just "//*[contains(text(),'Congratulations')]"  with a webdriverwait.  (I'm guessing that this element is loaded via javascript...but could also be a frame as mentioned above...)  You can then get the element's text by doing: ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");

Comment: No luck even after making the changes in the xpath and implementing webdriverwait. WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Congratulations')]")));
String text = ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");
System.out.println(text);

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[contains(text(),'Congratulations')] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: AND there is no iframe here.

Comment: Open the site in Chrome and walk through the steps and once you see the message, try your locator in the devtools console as `$x("//div[@class='form-header']//div[contains(text(),'Congratulations')]")`. Does it find the element?

Comment: No, it does not find the element. Upon giving this command - I am only seeing - "checking visibility" on the console.

Answer (score 0):

As the element is a dynamic element so to identify the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.form-header > div"))).getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `text()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-header']/div[text()='Congratulations!']"))).getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-header']/div[contains(., 'Congratulations')]"))).getText());
  ```

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-header']/div[text()='Congratulations!']")));
String text = ele.getText();
System.out.println(text);

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@class='form-header']/div[text()='Congratulations!'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)